# Odd white-space: pre behavior inside floated parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a simple responsive 2 column design, the left column has `pre` and a nested `code` elements in it.

The `code` element has `overflow: auto` set, so when its content exceeds its specified width, it should show a horizontal scrollbar inside it without wrapping the lines.

This works fine but only when the parent (i.e. the left column) is not floated. I.e. when the window is narrow. You can try it yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/46B6u/3/).

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
    .left {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 100px;
        max-width: 400px;
    }

    .right {
        float: right;
        margin-left: -100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
}

code {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is odd because I expect the code element to have a dynamic width like when it does when the window is narrow, but it acquires a fixed width for some reason when the parent is floated.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this supposed to happen?

Please note that I am not looking for a JS workaround, this is very simple html/css and should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated Fiddle, you gave the element in question a `max-width` of 400px to expand to. When it has a long line of text in it, it may take up that entire width. Basically, it's just your design being responsive to its content. The right column drops down below it exactly as it should, and if you resize the container to be smaller the `pre` block starts shrinking right along with it.

To see what I mean, right-click the element and `Inspect Element` to look at its calculated width. Also, if you think about it, it has to be 400px (or whatever the max width is). Otherwise, it hasn't reached its overflow point to acquire the scrollbars you were testing!

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. Updated the question. It should not wrap the lines. I just need it to show a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46B6u/3/). You see how the one below expands in width when you resize the Result pane? It gets a fixed width when the content inside `code` is lengthy.

Comment: Updated my answer. Essentially I think it looks counterintuitive, but when you squint at it correctly, your design is doing the right thing based on the way you set it up.